# GDAL Python API Warp and Translate Struggling with RGBA

Tags: python, gdal, gdalwarp, gdal-translate

Platform: Win7 Enterprise; PostgreSQL 9.6.1 with PostGIS 2.3.1; GDAL 2.1.3 and Python 2.7.11.

Like most people who try to do Python things Pythonically, I was pleased when it seemed that there was no more need to run `gdalwarp` and/or `gdal_translate` through `os.system()` or `subprocess()`. That was short lived once I attempted to fail my way to a working implementation of the Python API calls.

Every now and then I take a 10cm/px aerial of a major city, and snip out an image for every single property boundary so that I can run the images through an image classifier (in order to do some land-use change stuff).

Making a bunch of calls to the command line from within Python always felt kludgy and half-baked, and memory leaks start to add up to a big number.

So I spent some time thrashing through the documentation for key aspects of each GDAL Python API call (for example: `creationOptions` - is its argument an array? is it a `dict` of `key: value` pairs? or is it the worst possible choice - `["option=value","option=value"]`? Nobody seemed to want to write down which it was.)

I have started the process with one chunk of the gigantic ECW (the full thing is 131GB, so the task gets done in stages). I have chopped the chunk up into ~3million TIFFs using the BB of the property boundaries. That bit went according to plan; the code (the bit that repeats ~3m times) looks like this

```
    gdal.Warp(ofn, # the identifier of the parcel, plus '.tif'
          df,      # the first chunk of the behemoth ECW 
          format='GTiff',
          cutlineDSName='PG:' + cs, # cs is the PG connection string
          cutlineSQL=sql_01,        # cut geometry via PG is faster
          cropToCutline=True,  # <- obviously
          copyMetadata=True,
          metadataConflictValue=None,
          srcAlpha=True,
          dstAlpha=True,
          creationOptions=["PHOTOMETRIC=RGB"],
          setColorInterpretation=False,
          callback=None,
          callback_data=None)
```

You might think that `setColorInterpretation` maybe ought to be `true`: that's what I thought, but that guaranteed a 100% failure rate.

So far so good.

The usual next step is to run another loop which

- masks out NODATA using the alpha layer (leaving a 'tilted' image);
- finds the MBR for the tilted image (which has, as its second element, the dangle-angle);
- tilts the image 'upright' by the reverse of the dangle-angle (i.e., so that the longest side of the image is one of the two vertical sides); and
- chucks CUDA at the 3 million 'regularised' images so that a CNN can categorise them faster and more accurately.

As you might glean from the foregoing, I do not need to retain the spatial information about the sub-images: I have all that in the PostGIS data that drives the process that cuts the big ECW into bits.

If I remain within Python, the process stops after the chopping-up-the-raster stage, because **something prevents GDAL from recognising the fourth layer**.

QGIS can see the 4th layer, and the 4th layer is **exactly** what I want it to be: `255` inside the image, and `0` outside.

`CV2` has the same problem with the image/s as `GDAL`. I am pretty sure that it means that internally, its code just checks the `colorspace` string rather than looking for the number of child layers.

This is a process that I've done two dozen times with kludgy `os` calls, and it consumes significant resources.

I could probably get the next stage done with `gdal_translate` through `subprocess`  - that's what has worked in the past, and the image has metadata that is not structurally different from past versions of the same task.

The API is clearly more efficient - the `gdal.Warp` (slice-and-dice) part took less than half the time that the non-API version used to take.

Searches of the web show a low incidence of `PER_DATASET ALPHA` and `gdal ecw "band 1 has no color table"`.

Has anybody seen this phenomenon - where an RGBA raster is telling software that it's only RGB (despite advertising one of its **FOUR** layers as 'ALPHA') and the software is believing it?

Here's what `gdalinfo` says about the imagery (my thoughts are the coloured bits):

[image]

I could `algebra` a way through it - treat it as a `numpy` array and do some linear algebra - but I am actually really quite keen to improve this workflow so I can pass the task to someone else.

Comment: What do you mean by "something prevents GDAL from recognising the fourth layer" and "CV2 has the same problem with the image/s as GDAL"? Are the 4th bands not present? (`gdalinfo` says they are.) Is your problem with libraries interpreting the images as RGB and not RGBA by default?